# How to use Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a layout like this:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="deeper">
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="deeper">
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have to align the `div`s like: All the `div`s with "outer" class has to start from new line and all the `div`s with "inner" class has to be in the same line within "outer" `div` and the `div`s with deeper class inside "outer" `div` should start from new line and the "newLineContent" `div`s has to be in the same line within "deeper" `div`s

How can I achieve this using flexbox? or is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: We really need an image of the proposed layout to understand what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I keep coming back to this [css flex tutorial](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/css/flex-tutorial) lately, because of the interactive examples.

Answer (score 4):

One can do similar without Flexbox, thought Flexbox appears to be the best in this case.

```css
.outer,
.deeper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.inner {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: lightgray;
}
.inner:last-child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.newLineContent {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="deeper">
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="deeper">
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

If the `deeper` can be a child to any of the `inner`, and to achieve similar result, one would need either a parent selector, which doesn't exist, or give the `inner` an additional class for those that contain a `deeper`.

Another possible workaround could be to use viewport units `vw`.

```css
.outer,
.deeper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: calc(100vw - 40px);   /* 40px to make up for body's margins/scrollbar */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: lightgray;
}
.deeper {
  width: calc(100vw - 62px);   /* 62px is to make up for "inner" padding/border, 22px,
                                  and 40px for body's margins/scrollbar        */
}
.newLineContent {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="deeper">
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="deeper">
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
      <div class="newLineContent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the "deeper" divs to start from a new line. Here it starts in the same line of "inner" divs. But i need the "inner" div containing "deeper" divs to start from a new line

Comment: @Keshav1007 Updated...better?

Comment: awesome.. but instead of last-child how can i apply the same style for "inner" divs containing "deeper" div because the "deeper" div can come inside any "inner" div

Comment: @Keshav1007 You can't do that with the above, as there is no selector that can style the `inner` based on if there is a `deeper` or not. What you can do is to use viewport units `vw` to achieve such effect: https://jsfiddle.net/hn1dzg9p/

Comment: @Keshav1007 Let me know if it helped, and I can add it to my answer

Comment: @Keshav1007 Updated my answer anyway, as someone else might need this

Answer (score 2):

```
.outer{
  display: flex;
}
```

Simple as that! How you configure parent and child options, depends on the effect you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with ***Flexbox***:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: space-between; /* MDN: The items are evenly distributed within the alignment container along the main axis. The spacing between each pair of adjacent items is the same. */
}

.inner:last-child .deeper {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">1.1</div>
  <div class="inner">1.2</div>
  <div class="inner">1.3
    <div class="deeper">
      <div class="newLineContent">1.3.1</div>
      <div class="newLineContent">1.3.2</div>
      <div class="newLineContent">1.3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">2.1</div>
  <div class="inner">2.2</div>
  <div class="inner">2.3
    <div class="deeper">
      <div class="newLineContent">2.3.1</div>
      <div class="newLineContent">2.3.2</div>
      <div class="newLineContent">2.3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With your current *HTML structure* this is the result you get. *Flex-items* of the `.inner:last-child .deeper` div can't *stretch* the full *width* of the browser because the `.deeper` div represents one third of the *parent element*, i.e. the `.outer` div.